How to replicate pattern matching behavior in a C# 4 switch statement? Feature 'pattern matching' is not available in C# 4
I'm getting a

Feature 'pattern matching' is not available in C# 4

error in my C# code. I'm using a large switch statement with multiple cases.
switch (Name)
{
    case string a when a.Contains("Some string" + num):
        Temp = MiddleName;
        break;
    // ... other cases
}

I understand that pattern matching was introduced in C# 7. Is there a way to achieve similar functionality in C# 4? It's a huge project, I don't have the option to upgrade.

use if else statements

...why are you getting errors about C# 4.0? We're on C# 12 now (for .NET 8) - or C# 7.3 for .NET Framework 4.8.1 or earlier (indeed, you can even use C# 7.3 to target .NET Framework 2.0 if you know what you're doing). The only place I'd ever expect to see a C#-only csc.exe is in a brand-new install of Windows 8...

As well as many recent features working fine on older frameworks, if you're really using a version of the framework that only naturally supports C# 4, that would suggest you're using a version which is out of support. I would very strongly urge you to upgrade - if you upgrade to a new version of the .NET Framework (e.g. 4.8) it's likely to "just work" anyway. The longer you put it off, the worse this is going to get for you - and the more likely you are to run into a security problem in an unsupported version.

"It's a huge project, I don't have the option to upgrade." If it's a huge project, then your team has the obligation to push upgrades onto the roadmap regularly and just do them. I consider vastly outdated projects a) broken and b) a threat to security.

Just add a <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion> in a property group of your .csproj. Then you will be able to use a lot of the newest language features (including pattern matching) even with a very old framework version.

"It's a huge project, I don't have the option to upgrade." This is not a reason preventing you from upgrading. It just means it will take more time than a small project.

You can always use a good old if-else statement:
if (Name is string && ((string)Name).Contains("Some string" + num))
{
    Temp = MiddleName;
}
else if (...) // some condition for another case
{
}
// ... other cases
else // default case
{
}

